# Creating a CSS assembly, floating divs left, right and bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "pattern" of divs that looks like this:
[image]

However, currently it looks more like this:
[image]

resulting in my page looking something like this:
[image]

In that final snip, everything is also pushed to the right. Ideally, I need the assembly to be centred. The `Get Conditions` button should also reside underneath the `Print Runs` textbox, as they both reside in the same div, and be centred beneath the two upper divs. The dropdown lists and radiobutton list are both where they should be.

I toyed with floating the bottom div, but the various things I tried mostly resulted in the lower div taking up more space between the two upper divs.

I have pasted the HTML and CSS in a JSFiddle, please bear in mind that it doesn't recognise ASP tools so doesn't give an accurate preview of what I'm trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/h4tr31gt/1/

Comment: `clear` your floats

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work because you haven't included external code for one and for two, you cannot use C# in JSFiddle.

Comment: @DaniP can you expand on how this will help me?

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis I know, I just needed somewhere to put it where it could all be seen in a formatted manner, side by side. Pastebin doesn't really do that.

Comment: Without Clear https://jsfiddle.net/dzxevndv/ ..... **After Clear**  https://jsfiddle.net/dzxevndv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly address your question of floats, but you can achieve the same result by using flexbox.
https://jsfiddle.net/gnw634gv/

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.block-top {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-top">A</div>
  <div class="block-top">B</div>
  <div class="block-bottom">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there is one issue, the assembly is still aligned to the left. I've created a parent container that will also house some other elements underneath this assembly, can I use it to align everything on the page centrally? ftr, `text-align: center` has no effect. neither does `align-items`, which I thought would do since the children use flex.

Comment: Def take a look at the flexbox api. It is awesome! But if you want to "center" something within a flex container ( elem with `display: flex` ), use `justify-content: center`. Keep in mind, you can nest flex containers within each other if you need to! Flexbox is a bit weird to get your brain around, but once you do, you will never go back to floats.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

add a class of clearfix to the parent div, like so:

```
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
```

then add the following style to your css:

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

You can then reuse this anywhere else you are using floats.

https://jsfiddle.net/c3rLqce7/

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this is because some CSS attributes will also apply to the contents of a div, *including any divs inside it*?

Comment: Whilst that is true for some CSS attributes, I'm not sure if it applies here. What it does do though, is enough that the div will 'clear' the height of its contents. This means it will automatically adjust to be the size of its contents, and not shrink due to thinking it has less content, due to the floats. Reading up on floats on W3 schools will give you a better understanding of this, and practise of course. One of the most useful tools I use in Web Design.

Comment: Ah. Will it also clear the width? Because ideally, I would like the lower div to fill the width of the parent "container" div, where I can then centre its contents.

Comment: Here you go, take a look here. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp - but to answer your question, your best bet would be to put a div around your top two divs, and attach the clearfix class to that instead. Then your bottom div can go width: 100% and fill the parent. Let me know if that didn't make sense, and I will update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to demo what you were asking :)

Comment: I get it. Thanks, I'm trying both yours and @Pytth 's answer

Comment: Cool - let me know if you need any further info!

Answer (score 1):

As DaniP has suggested clearing floats would solve your issue. What float property does is removing your element from the actual page flow and aligning it according to your float value either right/left. So, when you try to add other element after the floated elements, it will occupy the page as if the floated elements doesn't exist. That is why you see that it is moved up. Also, floating the next element without clearing the previous elements floats will have the same result as without float. Hence, you need to clear the float using clear:both/right/left so that the surrounding of floated elements are cleared and you can align elements. You can check more on floats/clearfixes as some new things keep on arising every now and then. You might find it more clear.